# How can I wrap multiple elements that appear on the page multiple times with divs?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a form being generated through a CMS and I need to wrap the inputs and their labels to contain them within divs. Here's the HTML I have now:

```
<p><strong>Heading One</strong></p>
<p>Title One</p>
<input type="text" size="25" name="Title1" value="">
<br/>
<p>Title Two</p>
<input type="text" size="25" name="Title2" value="">
<br/>
<p>Title Three</p>
<input type="text" size="25" name="Title3" value="">
<br/>
<p>Title Four</p>
<input type="text" size="25" name="Title4" value="">
<br/>
```

This is what I'm hoping to achieve:

```
<p><strong>Heading One</strong></p>
<div class="wrapper">
     <p>Title One</p>
     <input type="text" size="25" name="Title1" value="">
</div>
<br/>
<div class="wrapper">
     <p>Title Two</p>
     <input type="text" size="25" name="Title2" value="">
</div>
<br/>
<div class="wrapper">
     <p>Title Three</p>
     <input type="text" size="25" name="Title3" value="">
</div>
<br/>
<div class="wrapper">
     <p>Title Four</p>
     <input type="text" size="25" name="Title4" value="">
</div>
<br/>
```

I tried this code here to achieve this:

```
$('form > p').each(function(){
    $(this).next('input[type="text"]').andSelf().wrapAll('<div class="wrapper"/>');
});
```

But it didn't work because it also wrapped the Heading p with the wrapper. Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Would be better to fix the problem at its root, the CMS. Which CMS is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(function() {
    $('input').each(function() { 
        $(this).prev().addBack()
        .wrapAll( $('<div/>',{class:'wrapper'}) );
    });
});
```

```js
$(function() {
    $('input').each(function() { 
        $(this).prev().addBack()
        .wrapAll( $('<div/>',{class:'wrapper'}) );
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><strong>Heading One</strong></p>
<p>Title One</p>
<input type="text" size="25" name="Title1" value="">
<br/>
<p>Title Two</p>
<input type="text" size="25" name="Title2" value="">
<br/>
<p>Title Three</p>
<input type="text" size="25" name="Title3" value="">
<br/>
<p>Title Four</p>
<input type="text" size="25" name="Title4" value="">
<br/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('p').not(':first-of-type').each(function() {
    var that = $(this);
    var div = '<div class="wrapper"></div>';
    that.next().addBack().wrap(div);
});
```

Comment: When I tried this in the console I got this error: "Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: first-of-type" Thanks for the help though :D